# WebSocket connection closed while sending message

Tags: javascript, react-native, websocket

So, here is what I am doing in react native. The socket is connected perfectly and able to receive a message but can't send a message.

```
    constructor(props) {

    super(props);

    this.state = { messages: [] };
    // this.onSend = this.onSend.bind(this);

    this.socket = new WebSocket('ws://34.212.65.102/ws/chat/81b55636-c495-4270-ad91-21a7ec7e7c73/');

    this.socket.onopen = () => {
        console.log('Socket connected...!');
    };

    this.socket.onmessage = (e) => {
        console.log('A message was received',e.data);
    };

    this.socket.onerror = (e) => {
        // an error occurred
        console.log('An error occurred', e.message);
    };

    this.socket.onclose = (e) => {
        // 
        console.log('connection closed', e.code, e.reason);
    };
}
```

And send message code

```
onSend(messages = []) {

    console.log('sending...');

    //this.socket.send(JSON.stringify({ "chat_uuid": "81b55636-c495-4270-ad91-21a7ec7e7c73", "message": "From vs code!!!!" }))
    let message = {
        'chat_uuid': '81b55636-c495-4270-ad91-21a7ec7e7c73',
        'message': {"chat_uuid":"81b55636-c495-4270-ad91-21a7ec7e7c73","message":"testtesfdfdfdfdfdfdfdttest"}
    }

    this.socket.send(JSON.stringify(message));
}
```

And here is an error:

```
connection closed 1011 null
```

The same thing working fine on the chrome extension **Simple WebSocket Client**

Here is I am attaching screenshots from extension:
[image]

Don't know what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

The message sent from your code is not the same as the message sent by the Chrome extension. Maybe you should try to send only

```
this.socket.send(JSON.stringify({"chat_uuid":"81b55636-c495-4270-ad91-21a7ec7e7c73","message":"testtesfdfdfdfdfdfdfdttest"}));
```